Postman is getting “Error: socket hang up” on Ubuntu, but works perfectly fine on windows
when i make a postman get request on windows pc it works perfectly fine , but on ubuntu i am getting Error: socket hang up
i make a request using axios too, it works perfectly fine on windows but when i make a request on Ubuntu i am getting the following error:
cause: Error: socket hang up
at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:524:23)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:531:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
sample URL: https://10.90.90.x:8989/v2/loanStatement/reconcilation/transactionLog/6660006663
